# Is there a way to use application that use hardware accelerated OpenGL on a headless machine?

Tags: linux, opengl, command-line, framebuffer, hardware-acceleration

There exist a class of applications that use opengl to provide hardware acceleration, but are not GUI based. However it seems that in the default case, to use opengl, there must be running an X-server with GLX (on the same virtual terminal) for those applications to function.

My specific case is attempting to use gstreamer's gl plugins on a headless machine, but I'm asking a more general question.

- *Is there some way around this (esp without modifying the original code)?*

I've been trying to research using the framebuffer kernel module, but not getting very far.

Comment: Hey! Have you been able to find the solution? It would also be great if you could recommend some cloud services which support such hardware acceleration for OpenGL?

Answer (score 1):

Mesa supports [software rasterization on offscreen surfaces](http://www.mesa3d.org/osmesa.html).

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of using hardware accelerated apis though.

Comment: @Catskul, mesa support hardware acceleration.

Comment: @J-16: The link specifically speaks of _software_ rasterization, which would obviously not be hardware accelerated.

Comment: @J-16 as I understand it, Mesa only supports hardware acceleration where it is the hardware driver itself. Though, admittedly my knowledge is thin here.

Comment: @Catskul Indeed Mesa can do X-less, HW accelerated offscreen OpenGL on the hardware where it also implements the usual OSS drivers. Though the whole things is largely experimental.

Comment: the OP explicitly asked for hardware acceleration

Answer (score 1):

You can use EGL and render to a PbufferSurface instead of a WindowSurface.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74226995/1884837

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Xvfb](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml)?

Comment: I have not. Do you know if it supports 3d acceleration?

Comment: @Catskul: Sorry, I don't.  It obviously wouldn't be *acceleration*, anyway - it would have to be a software implementation.

Comment: Theoretically it could take advantage of existing hardware if it were available, no?

Comment: @Catskul: In theory, but I don't think it's that smart.

Comment: @caf: Xvfb doesn't give you HW acceleration.

Comment: @datenwolf: I'm pretty sure that's what I said already in this comments thread (this answer was written before the mention of "hardware acceleration" was added to the question).