# OpenGL/OpenCL interoperability on headless server?

Tags: opengl, opencl, headless

**Is there a way to run app that uses OpenGL/OpenCL interoperability on a headless server?** Maybe without hardware acceleration. Maybe using some library for offscreen rendering.

Now there are plenty of popular cloud continuous integration services like drone.io or travis-ci. But testing projects that use OpenGL/OpenCL seems to be a problem still.

Comment: If you don't have an X server running on the server, I think you may simply be out of luck (without virtualization, at which point you might as well just test it once locally). I agree that testing graphics programs is a problem, are you sure there aren't specialized services that offer boxes with hardware acceleration? There has to be a market for that.

Comment: So far the only option I see is to use dedicated server, but they are usually quiete expensive, ecpessially if you want graphics card in it.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL/OpenCL interop usually is tied to a particular combination of OpenGL + OpenCL implementation. Normally the only combination of implementations working together are those, found in the same GPU driver package.

Mesa actually has some OpenCL support but I honestly don't know how well it works, what it constraints are and so on. Of course OpenCL is mostly useful only if you have a massively parallelizing processor available, like a GPU or a CPU cluster. There is a OpenCL implementation made by Intel targeting their multicore CPUs, but I don't know how well (if at all) it works with arbitrary OpenGL implementations.

If you have a OpenCL capable GPU available, then the easiest things to do, would be starting an X11 server with no or just a dummy screen configured (yes, this is possible).

Comment: The Intel runtime works well with OpenGL on Windows at least, I was able to share images, buffers and stuff between CL and GL. I suppose since it's a CPU implementation it's just passing through the requests to the actual OpenGL driver and mapping/copying transparently - for "proper" effective interop you certainly need both implementations to cooperate.

Comment: Then probably it will be able to interop with mesa OpenGL, at least for remote testing this solution will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

There definitely is a way. You can set up your OpenGL context using EGL and instead of a WindowSurface you can use a PbufferSurface.

```cpp
EGLDisplay display;
EGLSurface surface;
EGLContext context;

//bind desktop OpenGL
eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_API);
display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
eglInitialize(display, nullptr, nullptr);

//example constraints
const EGLint egl_config_constraints[] = {
    EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, static_cast<EGLint>(8),
    EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, static_cast<EGLint>(16),
    EGL_BUFFER_SIZE, static_cast<EGLint>(32),
    EGL_RED_SIZE, static_cast<EGLint>(8),
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, static_cast<EGLint>(8),
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE, static_cast<EGLint>(8),
    EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, static_cast<EGLint>(8),
    EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, EGL_FALSE,
    EGL_SAMPLES, 0,
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_BIT,
    EGL_CONFORMANT, EGL_OPENGL_BIT,
    EGL_CONFIG_CAVEAT, EGL_NONE,
    EGL_NONE };

EGLint configCount;
EGLConfig configs[1];

//find a fitting config
eglChooseConfig(display, egl_config_constraints, configs, 1, &configCount);

//set up the PbufferSurface
EGLint pbuffer_attrib_list[] = {
    EGL_WIDTH, WIDTH,
    EGL_HEIGHT, HEIGHT,
    EGL_NONE };
    
surface = eglCreatePbufferSurface(display, configs[0], pbuffer_attrib_list);

//setup the EGLContext
const EGLint contextVersion[] = {
    EGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4,
    EGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 6,
    EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_PROFILE_MASK, EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT,
    EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_DEBUG, debug ? EGL_TRUE : EGL_FALSE,
    EGL_NONE };
context = eglCreateContext(display, configs[0], EGL_NO_CONTEXT, contextVersion);
eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context);
eglSwapInterval(display, 1);
```

The above code is a rather comprehensive example on how to do this. I have taken the code from my own project https://github.com/kallaballa/GCV/blob/1052a3d9dda2acb1642ab695f10459f30092bf00/src/common/subsystems.hpp#L476 which can do on- and offscreen rendering.
Please refere to the README if you want to compile and run the OpenGL/OpenCL/VAAPI interop demos in this repo.